# Android Material Text Input Layout End Icon Not Showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to add an end Icon Drawable to my text input layout. I've come across the methods to do so but when I try to implement it, it does not work.

Material io says that all that is needed to display a trailing icon is to add `app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/your_icon_here"` When I do this I do not get an icon to display. The Icon I am using was downloaded as an SVG from Google's material icons library and I imported it into project as a vector asset.

Below is my code and a picture of the results I get. (I've broken the lines to make finding the call for the icon easier)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
  android:id="@+id/input_layout_event_name"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:hint="@string/ec_event_name"

  app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp"

  app:errorEnabled="false"
  app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent">

     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       android:id="@+id/input_event_name"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="textAutoCorrect" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Results in simulator of above code]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

End icon isn't visible because it's disabled by default (END_ICON_NONE). Add this attribute to `TextInputLayout`:

```xml
app:endIconMode="custom"
```

Comment: This is quite stupid from the API perspective, because both start and end icon should have the same options in the same way available. Start icon is shown immediately.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use this way:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar"
    app:endIconMode="custom">
```

Answer (score 4):

I know that issue is old, but for the devs after 2023, the InputTextLayout is doesn't showing the icons in preview, but if you run the app, the icons will be there.
Just do something like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_vamep_input_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_your_icon" //Your icon here
    app:endIconMode="custom" //Don't forget it
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextInputEditText.../>

 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:drawableEnd` in your `TextInputEditText`:

```xml
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/your_icon_here"
```

Comment: This works if added to the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` which isn't exactly what I wanted but it works well enough that I'm going to run with it. Just a note for anyone in the future using this method sets the icon slightly lower than it would if attempted with my original method.

Comment: No. Using `TextInputLayout` you should avoid the usage of `android:drawableEnd`. You need to add `app:endIconMode="custom"` to the `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed attribute `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` or `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` at `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: I don't understand what is the logic behind but after adding this line my icon is showing app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

Comment: Attribute above permit toggle, click to change Icon of eye is corresponding with status of password is hide or show. You can also control show/hide password by code.

//Show Password:
`editText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance())`

//Hide Password:
`editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance())`

Comment: @HanNguyen's answer is for those who want to add a custom password toggle drawable (i.e. hide/show eye icon) as an end icon. It's what I was looking for. Adding the `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` property works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
app:endIconMode="custom"
app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_calendar_24"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer). For example, you have used a drawable `ic_baseline_edit_calendar_24` which might not be present in the OPs code.